# How to compare a string of one column of pandas with rest of the columns and if value is found in any column of the row append a new row?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe, machine-learning

[image]

I want to compare the Category column with all the predicted_site and if value matches with anyone column, append a column named rank and insert 1 if value is found or else insert 0

Comment: can you post the data as data and not as a screenshot

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) for `predicted` columns compared by [`DataFrame.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) with `Category` column, convert to integers, change columns names by [`DataFrame.add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) and last add new columns by [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'category':list('abcabc'),
         'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'predicted1':list('adadbd'),
         'predicted2':list('cbarac')
})
df1 = df.filter(like='predicted').eq(df['category'], axis=0).astype(int).add_prefix('new_')
df = df.join(df1)
print (df)
  category  B predicted1 predicted2  new_predicted1  new_predicted2
0        a  4          a          c               1               0
1        b  5          d          b               0               1
2        c  4          a          a               0               0
3        a  5          d          r               0               0
4        b  5          b          a               1               0
5        c  4          d          c               0               1
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution is much less elegant than that proposed by @jezrael, however you can try it.

```
#sample dataframe
d = {'cat': ['comp-el', 'el', 'comp', 'comp-el', 'el', 'comp'], 'predicted1': ['com', 'al', 'p', 'col', 'el', 'comp'], 'predicted2': ['a', 'el', 'p', 'n', 's', 't']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

#iterating through rows
for i, row in df.iterrows():
  #assigning values
  cat = df.loc[i,'cat']
  predicted1 = df.loc[i,'predicted1']
  predicted2 = df.loc[i,'predicted2']
  #condition
  if (cat == predicted1 or cat == predicted2):
    df.loc[i,'rank'] = 1
  else:
    df.loc[i,'rank'] = 0
```

output:

```
       cat predicted1 predicted2  rank
0  comp-el        com          a   0.0
1       el         al         el   1.0
2     comp          p          p   0.0  
3  comp-el        col          n   0.0
4       el         el          s   1.0
5     comp       comp          t   1.0
```